# How to step in a conditional if in eclipse debugging

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I have the following structure :

```
if (obj.isSomethingable()){ 
// do something }
```

How can I enter the conditional if obj.isSomethingable() is false and I can't modify the boolean instance from obj ?

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense to me...why are you trying to debug code that shouldn't be executed in the current context?

Comment: i want to see what happens if it is executed. If i use boolean bol = obj.isSomethingable() then I can set bol to true and enter the conditional. But I want a way to enter it without modifying the code

Comment: Are you able to change how you create this object ? A subclass with overridden method can be useful for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the only way to do this is to modify the source code.

```
boolean bol = obj.isSomethingable();
if (bol) { ... }
```

After that you can change the boolean from Variables to true.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the eclipse's Display tab to execute the code is in //do something.

So if you have:

```
if(obj.isSomethingable())
{
  int var =5;
  System.out.println(var+8);
}
```

Then while at the if breakpoint in the display tab you can put in:

```
int var =5;
System.out.println(var+8);
```

Then highlight it all and click the magnifying glass to see what the output of that code would be.

Comment: I have a 'return true;' there. Executing that has no effect

Comment: It makes a lot of sense, trust me.

Comment: If all that you have in the conditional is a return statement, then it would seem that what you're really testing is the behavior of the caller on receiving a return of true. Am I missing something?

Comment: It seems what you are really asking is how to change how the program runs when in the debugger.  That is, you don't want to execute the method as it will normally, since you want it to return instead of executing the rest of the code.  Don't know of any debugger that will accomplish this.  Now if someone tied AOP into a debugger so user input could be injected at any point, you would be golden.

Answer (score 1):

Salut,

While in the Debug perspective, open the "variables" tab. you can select your object and change it's value. This will work for primitives or simple objects, but not on complex ones.
I've tried the following:

```
return new MyObj() {
    public boolean isSomething() {
        return true;
    }
};
```

But eclipse won't allow you to use annonymous classes.
You might try with a mock or something. Google mockito and see if it might work for you.

Tiberiu

Answer (score 0):

Before executing the `if`, use the debugger to change the state of `obj` in such a way that `isSomethingable()` will return true.